# Python Storing predefined lists in a module and editing them in an easy way

Tags: python

I'm not sure if this is best done with a class or if there's a neater way to do this.

I am writing a module, and in it I would like certain lists to be pre-defined and easily accessible, but also changeable. There will be a lot of these lists, maybe 20-30.

So example of these lists:

```
fruits = ['apple','pear','peach']
nuts = ['peanuts','cashew','almonds']
```

I also want to have two functions that allow people to add or remove items from this list:

```
my_mod.add(nuts, ['macademia','brazil'])
my_mod.remove(fruits, ['apple'])
```

So I was thinking of writing a class:

```
class Food:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.fruits = ['apple','pear','peach']
        self.nuts = ['peanuts','cashew','almonds']

    def add(self, add_items):
        self.<????> += add_items
```

But as you can see where I have the question marks, if I do it this way, I don't know how to add it to the list name supplied by the user.

Am I going about this there right way or is there a better way to achieve what I'd like?

The other idea I had was to use a `dict` and define it in the `__init__` file of the **Module**

But I'm less keen on this idea, as I think it could be confusing.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Each list name will be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## There is a couple ways you can do this:

**1 - With lists and "eval" function:   This one works; but is not adviseable, beacause using "eval" if you don't know what your doing a user can inject malicious code.**

```
class User:
    fruits = ['apple','pear','peach']
    nuts = ['peanuts','cashew','almonds']

    def add(self, _list, new_items=[]):
        l = eval('self.%s' % _list)
        l += new_items

    def remove(self, _list, item):
        l = eval('self.%s' % _list)
        l.remove(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    user1 = User()
    user1.add('fruits', ['orange', 'lemon'])
    print user1.fruits

    user1.remove('nuts', 'cashew')
    print user1.nuts
```

**2 - Using python dictionaries.**

```
class User:
    products = {
                    'fruits': ['apple','pear','peach'],
                    'nuts': ['peanuts','cashew','almonds'],
                }

    def add(self, _list, new_items=[]):
        try:
            self.products[_list] += new_items
        except KeyError:
            print 'The product list entered does not exist'

    def remove(self, _list, item):
        try:
            self.products[_list].remove(item)
        except KeyError:
            print 'The product list entered does not exist'

if __name__ == '__main__':

    user1 = User()
    user1.add('fruits', ['orange', 'lemon'])
    print user1.products['fruits']

    user1.remove('nuts', 'cashew')
    print user1.products['nuts']

    # When the user enters a nonexisting list
    user1.add('vegetables', ['onion'])
```

## 3 - Or the shortest way using a custom class of the list function.

```
class Mylist(list):
    def add(self, item):
        self.append(item)

class User:
    fruits = Mylist(['apple','pear','peach'])
    nuts = Mylist(['peanuts','cashew','almonds'])


if __name__ == '__main__':

    user1 = User()


    # TO ADD AN ITEM

    user1.fruits.add('orange')
    print user1.fruits


    # TO REMOVE AN ITEM, (list name must match name of list attribute inside)
    
    user1.nuts.remove('cashew')
    print user1.nuts
```

Comment: Answer 3 is exactly what I needed. Very clever... Thank you very much

Comment: Great that I can help!

Comment: And if you want to add new list's to the User module, all you have to do is: user1.grains = Mylist([])

Comment: so the only thing I can't figure out is how to remove items. I tried using the `.remove` method and it gets stuck in a loop, and I also tried a list comprehension:     `def remove(self, item):
        if item in self :
            self = [s for s in self if s != item]`
And in this case, nothing happens when I call it (but no error). Appreciate any advice. Cheers

Comment: I know this might be confusing this was also confusing to me when I was understanding classes,

Comment: Ok the part that I think is confusing to you is the missing remove method in Mylist() class, I also see in your comments that you tried to add a "def remove()"  method, but this is not necessary, since Mylist()   class is a subclass from the superclass  "list()" it inherits from the " list()" object all it's attributes, and methods, and since "list" object already has a method called "remove", we don't need to creat it.

Comment: The only reason we created an "add" method inside the "Mylist()" class is because the method to add an item in a "list()" object is called "append", but we wanted to use "add" instead of append,  so we created our own custom class and added the "add" method to it, and inside that method we excecute the "append" statement that is needed to add new items using the "list()" object ej.

Comment: instead of using     newitem.append(), with the custom "Mylist()"  you do newitem.add()

Comment: and "Mylist()" object already has a "remove()" method that was inherited from "list" object, so not need to define one

Comment: Note:  If you were to add a "remove" method to "Mylist()" class and inside you did not add a "self.remove(item)" statement, you will effectively override the "remove" method from the inherited "list" class, and remove will not work any more, so trust me on this, you do NOT need to define a "def remove()" method to "Mylist()" class, or "User()" class, "Mylist" inherits that automatically from "list" object.

Comment: To remove an item from outside "User" class:      user1.fruits.remove('orange')   --      To remove an item from inside the "User" class:     self.fruits.remove('orange')

Comment: Super helpful. Very clear now. Thanks and appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use an `.xml` or `.json` to define the contents of this list, like a sort of config. That way you can in your python code, simply read the `root` level `tree` and drill down programmatically, without the need to hard code anything, yet give the end users flexibility to add/remove. This can also mean that the end user changing this `config` file doesn't need to modify any `python objects`.

Let me illustrate. We have a config of user defined lists, say `udl_config.xml` which looks like:

```
<main>
    <fruits>
        <elem>apple</elem>
    .....
    </fruits>
    <nuts>
         .....
    </nuts>
    .....
</main>
```

Then in your python code you will have:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
main_tree = ET.parse('udl_config.xml')
main_root = main_tree.getroot()
```

Use the `find()` and `text()` functions of xml parse library to drill down dynamically and perform necessary actions on them.

Comment: Hi, ok let me try this. I've never worked with xml or json files before but it could be a good opportunity to learn.